# Length of chord DE

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the given circle |AB| = 10 Units and AB || CD

AB is the diameter of the circle.

What is the length of the chord ED?

Comment: Is $AB$ supposed to be a diameter of the circle?

Comment: Yes AB is the diameter of the circle.

Comment: I would be intrigued to know if it is possible without relying on trigonometry for the final calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inscribed angle of a cirle, $\angle CBE = \angle CDE = 15^\circ$. That means $\angle ABE = 25^\circ$. Since $AB$ is a diameter, $\angle AEB$ is right, and thus we conclude that $\angle BAE = 90^\circ - 25^\circ = 65^\circ$.

Since $\angle BAD = 10^\circ$ by symmetry, we have that $\angle DAE = 65^\circ - 10^\circ = 55^\circ$. If we let $O$ be the center of the circle, we know then that $\angle DOE = 2\cdot\angle DAE = 110^\circ$. Your unknown side is now the last side of an isosceles triangle with two sides $5$ long, since they are radii in the circle, and with angles $110^\circ$, $35^\circ$ and $35^\circ$. That should be easer to calculate.

Answer (score 4):

Common case $\angle ABC = \alpha, \angle CDE = \beta$:
[image]

Let $DF || BE \Rightarrow |ED|=|BF|$.

*$\angle CBE = \angle EDC = \beta$ - same chord.*
$\angle EBF = \angle BFD= \angle DCB= \angle ABC =\alpha$.

As $\angle AFB=\frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow |FB|=|AB|\cdot \textbf{cos} \angle ABF$.

So $|ED|=|AB|\cdot \textbf{cos} (2\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother but what tool do you use to draw images like the one you posted?

Comment: GeoGebra. http://www.geogebra.org

Comment: Many many thanks

Comment: @Mike: Manu many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

O is center of circle. and You must know that total angle of circle is 360 degree.